# Is there a better way of instantiating my class for Environment Objects? - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am currently sharing an environment object in using the following model class:

```
//
//  UserInfoModel.swift
//  CalorieTrackerDis
//
//  Created by Matthew Pearce on 01/12/2020.
//

import Foundation

class UserInfoModel: ObservableObject {
    
    
    struct UserInfo: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var firstName: String
        var lastName: String
        var height: Int
        var weight: Int
        var genderIsMale: Bool
        var age: Int
        
    }
    
    struct DailyCalorieGoals: Identifiable{
        var id = UUID()
        var calorieGoal: Int
        var fatGoal: Int
        var proteinGoal: Int
        var carbGoal: Int

    }
    
    struct CurrentCalorieProgress: Identifiable{
        var id = UUID()
        var calorieProgress: Int
        var fatProgress: Int
        var carbProgress: Int
    }
    
    @Published var personUserInfo = UserInfo.init(firstName: "", lastName:"", height: 0, weight: 0, genderIsMale: true, age: 0)
    @Published var personDailyCalorieGoals = DailyCalorieGoals.init(calorieGoal: 0, fatGoal: 0, proteinGoal: 0, carbGoal: 0)
    @Published var personCurrentCalorieProgress = CurrentCalorieProgress.init(calorieProgress: 0, fatProgress: 0, carbProgress: 0)
```

}

As you can see from the last few lines of my code, I instantiate a new object with empty values, is there a better way of creating new objects using all the structs without separating the object?

Comment: If there is no natural initual value you should consider making the properties optional otherwise you should use dependency injection so they are set via an `init`

Comment: It is not really clear the goal... what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Either make your properties optional and don't add a value when you init, or make personUserInfo an optional and don't init until you have values.